# Prism 7.1: No suitable method to override for methods RegisterTypes and CreateShell

Tags: wpf, prism

I am building my first app using Prism v7.1.  In App.xaml.cs, I have the following:

```
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Unity;
using System.Windows;

namespace ScanMiner
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        protected override Window CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        }
    }
}
```

I have red squiggly lines under RegisterTypes and CreateShell and an error that says no suitable method found to override.  I also have a red squiggly under Container. with an error message that says "The name 'Container' does not exist in the current context.

My App.xaml looks like this:

```
<prism:PrismApplication x:Class="ScanMiner.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScanMiner">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem turned out to be a red herring or maybe a Visual Studio bug.  While the errors were still present, I did a successful build of the solution, and the errors went away.